# FIRST_VALUE is not working

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm making this request but I get an error that

> OVER is not suported by sql

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE( JrnlStock.StockInitial) over (ORDER BY JrnlStock.date ASC),JrnlStock.Reference
where JrnlStock.Date > @Du
```

Comment: you are missing `FROM JrnlStock`

Comment: I've already put the "from JrnlStock" but it is still not working. I still have the same message "over is not suported by sql"

Comment: what is your database compatibility level? can you provide the entire query?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe syntax is not right. Where is the FROM clause ?
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx